# Corona SDK: addEventListener calling method at wrong time

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to add an event listener to a semi-transparent black background, which calls the cancel method, using the following code:

```
blackRect = display.newRect(display.contentWidth/2,
                            display.contentHeight/2,
                            display.contentWidth,
                            display.contentHeight)
blackRect:setFillColor(0)
blackRect.alpha = 0.9

local function cancel( ... )
    if blackRect then
        blackRect:removeSelf()
        blackRect = nil
    end
    if yesBtn then
        yesBtn:removeSelf()
        yesBtn = nil
    end
    if cancelBtn then
        cancelBtn:removeSelf()
        cancelBtn = nil
    end
    if getCoinsBtn then
        getCoinsBtn:removeSelf()
        getCoinsBtn = nil
    end
    if notEnoughCoins then
        notEnoughCoins:removeSelf()
        notEnoughCoins = nil
    end
    -- Body
end

blackRect:addEventListener("tap", cancel)
blackRect:addEventListener("touch", cancel)
```

However, the method cancel is being called when I call `addEventListener`, or at least that's what it looks like, since `blackRect` doesn't even show on the screen, and neither do the other objects that are created after the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing. You are saying that the "the method cancel is being called when I call addEventListener". It actually makes sense that is being called. Did you mean that "is NOT being called"?

I did test a simplified version of your code and works fine:

```
local blackRect = display.newRect(display.contentWidth/2,
                                  display.contentHeight/2,
                                  display.contentWidth,
                                  display.contentHeight)
blackRect:setFillColor(0)
blackRect.alpha = 0.9

local function cancel()
    print("executing cancel")
    if blackRect then
        print("removing blackRect")
        blackRect:removeSelf()
        blackRect=nil
    end
end

blackRect:addEventListener("tap", cancel)
blackRect:addEventListener("touch", cancel)
```

When I tap the blackRect box the EventListener is fired up and the object is removed. I added a couple of print statements that help see in the console that it actually gets there.

Comment: it is being called when I actually call blackRect:addEventListener, and not when I actually tap/touch blackRect

Comment: Try to move that code to a new empty main.lua file. It works fine for me. You may have something else interferring. I did test and it works fine.